# Приём только новых писем в The Bat!

Tags: email

Есть почтовый сервер, который работает на Керио мэйл-сервер. Керио собирает письма с хостинга и собственно хранит их уже локально. Почтовые клиенты письма забирают уже непосредственно с локального сервера. В виду того, что сервер работает уже несколько лет, то писем там уже за 10 000.

Почтовый клиент - The Bat!

Недавно были некоторые переустановки в системе и бат теперь хочет скачать все письма заново. Но все письма качать НЕ НАДО. Но и удалять их тоже нельзя оттуда.

Поэтому вопрос: как можно настроить бат, чтобы он принимал письма, скажем, только после 01.01.2011?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, нужно использовать протокол IMAP. В отличие от POP3, IMAP позволяет скачивать сообщения, не удаляя их с сервера, и выборочно.
Во-вторых, для начала получите заголовки всех писем, а потом уже качните то, что нужно, выбрав в почтовой программе.

Comment: А подробнее можно? А то я в БАТе что - то не очень.

Comment: см. <a href=http://subscribe.ru/archive/comp.soft.others.rusfaqthebat/200711/11140310.html>тут</a>

Comment: Спасибо, @gecube.

Comment: Поп3 тоже позволяет скачивать избранные письма...